# Configure CMake with CodeLite

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, codelite

How should I configure my file CMakeLists.txt to work with the structure of CodeLite project? Ss below and more in the comment.

CMakeLists.txt:

[image: CMakeLists.txt]

Thank you.

Comment: [Codelite Project][1]
[CMakeLists.txt][2]
[build.sh][3]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkwKP.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHVPz.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww52P.png